# Jquery AJAX promise with always break when ajax fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a loop with multiple ajax request.
each ajax is managed thru always callback.
each ajax is pushed in promises array.
finally $.when is used on always.

If all `$.ajax` got success the `$.when.apply($, promises).always(...);`
is called when all `$.ajax` calls succeed.

But for example on 3 `$.ajax` call the second fails, the `$.when.apply($, promises).always(...);` is fired only after the second and not when all `3 $.ajax` calls suceed.

Any help?
Following the code

```
$(".upload_all").bind("click", function() {
  var confirmed_count = 0;
  var error_count = 0;
  var promises = [];

  to_uploads.each(function(index,val) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var promise = $.ajax({
      url: "/upload/storeUploadedFile",
      type: 'POST',
    }).always(function(data_or_jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_or_errorThrown) {
      if (textStatus === "success") {
        // ..
      } else {
        // ..
      }                  
    });

    promises.push(promise);
  });

  $.when.apply($, promises)
    .always(function() {
      console.log("Promises Always! ") // do other stuff
    });
}
```

Comment: is .always even relevant with jquery promises? Yeah, guess i just never used it in that context. jquery 1.6+

Comment: Ok, so, what's happening is your $.when() creates one promise that either resolves or rejects. If one of the promises rejects, the whole thing rejects immediately, skipping any haven't finished. That suggests you have a promise that is failing if it isn't getting to them all. If you want to wait for them all to run regardless of failure, you'll have to intercept failures and convert them to successes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kevin-b mentions, the promise that `$.when` returns (pretty much the same as `Promise.all`) will be rejected if any of the promises passed to it is rejected. You probably want this, to inform the user that some uploads where not successful.

But `$.ajax(..).always` (the same as `promise.finally`) means 'execute this callback when this promise is either rejected or resolved'. You probably want instead to do something when all ajax call succeed, or do something else when any of them fails. Use `Promise.all(promises).then(...).catch(...)` for that.

```
$(".upload_all").bind("click", function() {
  var confirmed_count = 0;
  var error_count = 0;

  var promises = to_uploads.map(function(index,val) { // using map instead of each here saves us a couple of steps
    var elem = $(this);

    return $.ajax({
      url: "/upload/storeUploadedFile",
      type: 'POST',
    })
      .then(function() { confirmed_count += 1; })
      .catch(function() {
        error_count += 1;
        return Promise.reject(); // Return a rejected promise to avoid resolving the parent promise
      });
  });

  // You can use the native API here which does not require doing the `apply` hack
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function() { alert('All uploads successful'); })
    .catch(function() { alert(`Successful uploads: ${confirmed_count}. Failed uploads: ${error_count}`); }
}
```

Remember JQuery uses an alternative implementation of promises, but they still respond to the native API:

- `.then` (`.done` in JQuery flavor): attach a callback to be run on success
- `.catch` (`.fail` in JQuery flavor): attach a callback to be run on error. Unless a rejected promise is returned this will resolve the promise.
- `.finally` (`.always` in JQuery flavor): attach a callback to be run after any other callbacks run, despite of the promise being rejected or resolved.

Comment: where I commented     // do other stuff
I wish to prompt user with only one summary with success upload and failed upload.

you say "means 'execute this callback when this promise is either rejected or resolved'" but it doesn't happen as I tried to explain, because when one ajax fail the when callback was fired.

Comment: You can iterate over my changes and push a reference to the failed API calls into an array for example. You can't use `always` because it will fire both when all the AJAX call succeed  or when any fails. Look for the edit.